# How to stop a setInterval fired by mouseenter, upon mouseleave?

Tags: javascript, scroll, setinterval, mouseover, mouseenter

I've managed to get arrows which scroll the overflow of a div on `mouseenter` to work. The problem is that the script not only doesn't stop on `mouseleave`, but prevents to scroll the div opposite side manually.

JS

```
function scroll_right() {
        var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails")[0];
            elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
        var timer = setInterval(scroll_right, 300); 
}

function kill() {
        clearInterval(timer)
}
```

And the arrow

```
<img class="arrow" 
 onmouseenter="scroll_right()"
 onmouseleave="kill()" 
 src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126490.svg">
```

My idea was that `scroll_right` function gets fired on `mouseenter`, and the `timer` inside of it, gets deactivated on `mouseleave`.

Comment: Your code is almost correct except the following: you define `timer` in `scroll_right`, and thus you cannot access it in `kill`. So, put `var timer;` outside both functions, and then replace `var timer = ...` with `timer = ...` in `scroll_right`.

Comment: @alx notice that the `scroll_right` function set infinitely many timer after a period of time. See my answer for solution

Comment: @AnsonYeung Oops, you're right, that's the next big problem after invalid scope of `timer` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The timer is set every time the `scroll_right` function runs. There will be infinitely many timer running at the some time after a while. You can try using `setTimeout` function instead of the below one. Also, the scope of timer is limited to the function in your code.

```js
var timer = undefined;

function scroll_right() {
  var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails")[0];
  elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
  if (!timer) {
    timer = setInterval(scroll_right, 300);
  }
}

function kill() {
  if (timer) {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = undefined;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnails" onmouseenter="scroll_right()" onmouseleave="kill()" style="width:150px;overflow:auto">
  <img class="arrow" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126490.svg" width="500px">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you !
Works perfectly !

Answer (score 4):

You just have to create a global timer variable that will store setInterval() value, so that you can use it to stop setInterval running.

```
    var timer = undefined;

    function scroll_right() {
        var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails")[0]; 
        elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
        timer && clearInterval(timer);
        timer = setInterval(scroll_right, 300); 
    }

    function kill() {
        timer && clearInterval(timer)
    }
```

--------- this is html code

```
<img class="arrow" 
 onmouseenter="scroll_right()"
 onmouseleave="kill()" 
 src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/126/126490.svg">
```

Comment: sorry, silly mistake, i have edit the answer, now its working fine, you can try too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare timer variable outside function to be used by another function
Replace your JS with :

```
var timer;
function scroll_right() {
    var elmnt = document.getElementsByClassName("thumbnails")[0];
    elmnt.scrollLeft += 50;
    timer = setInterval(scroll_right, 300); 
}

function kill() {
    clearInterval(timer)
}
```